# All variations of a number

Tags: algorithm

Im trying to find all the possible variations of a number in the form of:
'1_2_3_4' where _ is a number between 0 to 9.
I was wondering what is the best approach to this problem.

Comment: 4 nested loops that go from '0' to '9'.

Comment: isnt there a better way?

Comment: @OplItay what would 'better' mean?

Comment: @AakashM better runtime.

Comment: Maybe threaded backtrack could be faster, but that's overkill

Comment: How would i write that?

Comment: @Cid How can you generate all combinations *without generating all combinations*?

Comment: You can't, ofc, but you may generate some at "the same time"

Comment: @NiVeR: four loops for three digits ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import java.util.*;
public class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int[] fillable = {1,-1,2,-1,3,-1,4};
        for(int i=0;i<=9;++i){
            for(int j=0;j<=9;++j){
                for(int k=0;k<=9;++k){
                    fillable[1] = i;
                    fillable[3] = j;
                    fillable[5] = k;
                    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(fillable));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
[1, 0, 2, 0, 3, 0, 4]
[1, 0, 2, 0, 3, 1, 4]
[1, 0, 2, 0, 3, 2, 4]
[1, 0, 2, 0, 3, 3, 4]
[1, 0, 2, 0, 3, 4, 4]
[1, 0, 2, 0, 3, 5, 4]
[1, 0, 2, 0, 3, 6, 4]
.
.
.
.
```

**Time Complexity:** O(10^n) where `n` is no. of places to fill in. If 3 empty places if fixed, then it is `O(1)`.

**Space Complexity:** O(1)

**Note:** There is **no** better way to do this. You have to go through each and every combination.

Answer (score 1):

This seems like the simplest method:

```
static void printPerms()
{
  int n = 1020304;
  for (int i = 0; i <= 9; i++, n += 90000)
    for (int j = 0; j <= 9; j++, n += 900)
      for (int k = 0; k <= 9; k++, n += 10)
        System.out.println(n);
}
```

Or even this, which has a lovely symmetry:

```
static void printPerms()
{
  int n = 1020304;
  for (int ni = n + 900000; n <= ni; n += 90000)
    for (int nj = n + 9000; n <= nj; n += 900)
      for (int nk = n + 90; n <= nk; n += 10)
        System.out.println(n);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Python style, assuming ASCII code representation:

```
n= "1020304"
while True:
    n[5]+= 1
    if n[5] == ':':
        n[5]= '0'
        n[3]+= 1
        if n[3] == ':':
            n[3]= '0'
            n[1]+= 1
            if n[1] == ':'=
                break
```